# Add key to dictionary on a for loop, getting runtimeerror

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am adding a new key to a dictionary with a value but keep running into a runtime error when I run the code. I am adding two separate key's at times in the same iteration. I'm able to get it to run when appending one key, but not two at the same time.

Code for adding items to dict that doesn't work:

```
    for data in list:
        for value in data:
            if value == 'timestamp':
                timestamp = data[value]
                minute_shred = timestamp[14:16]
                second_shred = timestamp[17:19]
                    #change to x,y
                if minute_shred[0] == '0' and second_shred[0] == '0':
                    minute_shred = timestamp[15:16]
                    second_shred = timestamp[17:19]
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
                    data['second'] = int(minute_shred)
                    print(data['second'], timestamp)
                    #no change to x,y
                elif minute_shred[0] != '0' and second_shred[0] != '0':
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
                    data['second'] = int(minute_shred)
                    print(data['second'], timestamp)
                    # change to x, not y
                elif minute_shred[0] == '0' and second_shred[0] != '0':
                    minute_shred = timestamp[15:16]
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
                    data['second'] = int(second_shred)
                    print(data['second'], timestamp)
                    #change to y, not x
                elif minute_shred[0] != '0' and second_shred[0] == '0':
                    second_shred = timestamp[18:19]
                    data['second'] = int(second_shred)
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
                    print(data['second'], timestamp)
```

This code works when only adding one key on an iteration.

```
    for data in list:
        for value in data:
            if value == 'timestamp':
                timestamp = data[value]
                minute_shred = timestamp[14:16]
                if minute_shred[0] == '0':
                    minute_shred = timestamp[15:16]
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
                elif minute_shred[0] != '0':
                    data['minute'] = int(minute_shred)
```

I also tried adding them one after the another, but it didn't work, the second for loop with logic for adding data['second] as it produces a runtime error. I did notice that if I changed data['second'] to data['minute] when adding the second_shred variable it works. Obviously, I need them to be added as two separate keys.

Comment: dont modify a dictionary(or any mutable iterable) while iterating it ...

Comment: I have a number of dictionaries within a list, how else can I modify it while iterating through it ..?

Comment: Create a copy and take that as reference! Iterating a dynamic object is always risky!

Comment: took me a minute to grasp, but thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, don't modify an iterable while iterating over it.

I strongly suggest using a map or a list comprehension if you want to iterate and modify data.

Example:

```
def modify(dict_val):
    # Code for modification as in your question

list = [map(modify, data) for data in list]
```

If you want to use this other than for future iteration, make sure to wrap the map in a `list()` if this is Python3.

Comment: I ended up using deepcopy and iterating through a loop, but my expression statements for using a list comprehension was too long so I didn't use comprehensions. Thanks for writing this alternative method!

Comment: No sweat. `deepcopy` tends to be quite slow, so avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Worked using deepcopy.

```
    listcopy = copy.deepcopy(list)
    for item in listcopy:
        itemcopy = copy.deepcopy(item)
        for k in itemcopy:
            if k == 'timestamp':
                timestamp = item[k]
                second_shred = timestamp[17:19]
                if second_shred[0] == '0':
                    second_shred = timestamp[18:19]
                    item['second'] = int(minute_shred)
                elif second_shred[0] != '0':
                    item['second'] = int(minute_shred)
```